# Big O time complexity for nested for loop (3 loop)

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

```
def unordered pair(arrayA, arrayB):
    for i in range(len(arrayA)):
        for j in range(len(arrayB)):
           for k in range(0, 100000):
               print(arrayA[i] + arrayB[j])
```

I just started Big O and need help on this example. If I tried to get the time complexity for each line, I know the first loop (for i loop) + the second loop (for j loop) equals **O(ab)**. However, what is the time complexity for the last loop? (for k loop). I thought it should be **O(n)** since its just a simple for loop from 0 to n, but it turns out to be **O(1)**? Why is that? Thank you

Comment: Firstly, it's Big O, not Big 0. Secondly, you are not defining `a` and `b`. Apparently you meant the length of `arrayA` and `arrayB`, but you should state that explicitly. Lastly, all constant-time operations are O(1), 10000 is a constant, so the last for loop is O(1). If you don't understand the last point, review your complexity analysis course.

Comment: Because `100000` is constant and it's values doesn't depend on input size. So this statement is like you've written `arrayA[i] + arrayB[j]` 100000 times. Where complexity of each statement is constant and therefore it will be constant.

Comment: As mentioned above, a constant number of operations (no matter how big the constant is) are in O(1). See here more info about big-O: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appreciate that the third loop in `k` is actually fixed number of iterations, 100000 to be exact.  This means that this third inner loop really just is a multiplier to the complexity of the outer two loops, and therefore won't affect the overall complexity by more than a constant.

The complexity of the two outer loops is just `O(N*M)`, where `N` is the size of `arrayA` and `M` is the size of `arrayB`.  Therefore, the overall complexity of the three nested loops is `O(100,000 * N * M)` which is just `O(N*M)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the range for loop k is 0-100000 the time it will take will be constant.Hence O(1). I think the term is amortized time?

Comment: Amortization has nothing to do with it. It's just a constant.